# Real time notification on user profile after new comment

Tags: php, customization, comments

I am creating a listing website on which i want to notify post author on new comment and notify users on reply of their comment . I want notification on profile page .How I do this?
Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Real time is not possible in web but you can make a AJAX request every 5 seconds e.g. to check for new comments. Read this : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: @mmm that's inaccurate, websockets exists and can be made in php (even managed to do one within wp)

Answer (score 0):

this Wordpress plugin can help you : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpdiscuz/

thanks.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148136)

Comment: Hi Jacob Peattie, link which i have included is wordpress plugin so there are less chances that linked page changes